# Typed locales in typescript based on country and available languages

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given something like

```
interface Country {
     "SE": {
         langs:  {sv:"sv", fi: "fi", en: "en"} 
     }
     'US': {langs:  {us:"us", ca: "ca", es: "es"} }
}

type Market = "SE" | "US"
```

I would like the type system to know that the only valid locales are:

```
"sv-SE"
"fi-SE"
"en-SE"
"ca-US"
"en-US"
"es-US"
```

Is this possible? The best I could come up with is:

```
type Locale = `${keyof Country}-${keyof Country[Market]["langs"]}`

let locale: Locale = "" => never
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
interface Country {
  "SE": {
    langs: { sv: "sv", fi: "fi", en: "en" }
  }
  'US': { langs: { us: "us", ca: "ca", es: "es" } }
}

type Code<T> =
  T extends keyof Country
  ? keyof Country[T]['langs'] extends string
  ? `${keyof Country[T]['langs']}-${T}`
  : never
  : never

type US = Code<'US'>
type SE = Code<'SE'>

//thanks @sroes
type Locale = Code<keyof Country>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsCu4oE9kDeAsAFDLIBEAygKIUBchp55ANnCAOYDOjBy3AG6MKQigBpkMYCOkTkEECMUVkAX2brNAcgCqVbX2TsuvQskxmKl%20Qjgi78iFeeq1WkhpKlSYXAAcUADU4VkxnAB4AFQA%20ZABeZCiAbQBrCFx0GCSAXR8SP0C0dAATCGi4%20M0ohQAPSBAS7mR0zOyMbDA8TQB%20Foys4s68ZKic5O0THm0cuoamgS7QTl7kAAMAEgJWwY6cXFHxyY5pnLUAWi2otTXNRhAIQWg75AenqHzClH0E4rKIvQGGK%20AIoWi-DD-bS0bTAkhAA)

Comment: And then `type Locale = Code<keyof Country>`

Answer (score 4):

For the guys visiting from the future, this is now possible with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html). For example,

```
type Country = 'US' | 'GB';
type Lang = 'en';

type Locale = `${Lang}_${Country}`; // type Locale = "en_US" | "en_GB"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a single generic helper mapped type that is independent of the current `Country` list to get the desired result:

```ts
interface Country {
     "SE": {
         langs:  {sv:"sv", fi: "fi", en: "en"} 
     }
     'US': {langs:  {us:"us", ca: "ca", es: "es" } }
}

type Locale<CL> = {
  [ U in keyof CL  ] : CL[U] extends { langs: { [ x: string ] : string } }  ? `${keyof CL[U]["langs"] & string}-${U & string}` : never
}[keyof CL & string];

type invalid = Locale<{ "UU": { langs: "EEE" } }>; //never;

type custom = Locale<{ "EU": { langs: { fr: "fr" } } }>; //"fr-EU";

type valid = Locale<Country>; //"sv-SE" | "fi-SE" | "en-SE" | "us-US" | "ca-US" | "es-US"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=67&pln=14&pc=1#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)